# get the request of an authorized client in the API side?

Tags: django, python-2.7, api, django-rest-framework

I need to get the response from an authorized client, the client has a token to request books from an API, so my code is the following:

```
class BooksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [TokenHasScope]
    required_scopes = ['books']
```

here I need to know which books are requested to do a query and return a response to the client, how can I figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override `get_queryset` like so:

```
class BooksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [TokenHasScope]
    required_scopes = ['books']

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Replace this queryset with the books you want to query for.
        # You can use self.request to access parameters.
        return Book.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks !  "self.request " is what i need using a genericAPIView

booktitle = float(self.request.query_params.get('booktitle'))